# caconstraint vs. nslayoutconstraint

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, autolayout

For a new app that is going to have a fairly complex gui with lots (hundreds) of (nested) graphics containing each just a word, an image, a path a gradient or a path. only part of them are actual ui elements requiring ui interaction.

Now it seems to me the most sensible thing would be to use a mix of CALayers & NSViews + CAConstraint & NSLayoutConstraint.

So what's the relation between CAConstraint & NSLayoutConstraint? (is the latter just a superset of the former?)

what are the tradeoffs? (i guess CALayer+CAConstraint is more efficient)

i already know that:
* CAConstraint is not supported on iOS (really don't care)
* NSLayoutConstraint is marginally more powerful (priority based conflict breaking, non-equal relations, IB & string based setup)